# Python Pandas, Export string columns into Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working with codes from dataframe column, example: case_id=211246842501
When I export to excel file show me something like this case_id= 2112+17
Even if I convert the value into string:

```
EUROC= pd.read_excel(f'{NewFilePath}{NewFile}', sheet_name="EUROC")   
EUROC['case_id']=EUROC['case_id'].values.astype(str)
FileFinal='Test Prueba.xlsx'
full_path_file = f'{ICSPath}{FileFinal}'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_path_file, engine='xlsxwriter', )
EUROC.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='EUROC', index=False)
```

What I can do to show the hole number? It can be string value I don't have issues with that but I need that the real value show us in the excel.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Can you add an image of the output you are describing with the `case_id=2112+17` in Excel? It sounds like the value may in fact be in the excel document, but the column widths may need to be set in order to display by default.

Comment: @JoeThor Excel automatically converts large enough numbers to scientific notation, there is no way around it other than to set the column or cells to text and then paste the number in.

Comment: This is an example show me this 8.19195861645729e+17 instead this 819195861645728953

Answer (score 0):

could not test the program as sample data not available but objective to see full case_id can be accomplished theoritically with following

```
EUROC= pd.read_excel(f'{NewFilePath}{NewFile}', sheet_name="EUROC")   
EUROC['case_id']=EUROC['case_id'].values.astype(str)
EUROC['case_id'] = EUROC.apply(lambda x: "'" + str(x.case_id) , axis = 1)  #added line
FileFinal='Test Prueba.xlsx'
full_path_file = f'{ICSPath}{FileFinal}'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_path_file, engine='xlsxwriter', )
EUROC.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='EUROC', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi show me this '8.19195861645729e+17 instead this 819195861645728953

Comment: Please check dataframe 'case_id' value before writting to excel. it's my guess, that dataframe value has been changed to '8.19195861645729e+17. u can remove line 2 for checking the result once.

Comment: Hi @ahmedul_Kabir_Omi, please check the attached image at the beginning of the post, even if I dont make transformation show me wrong values.